# connecting to clickhouse in R

Tags: r, database, clickhouse, dbconnect

I am new to clickhouse. I am trying to set connection in the following way:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(clickhouse::clickhouse(),
    host="localhost",
    port=8123L,
    user="default",
    password="")
```

but I get this error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : dbIsValid(con) is not TRUE

I have tested the authentication and they are correct. I also check the connection with dbCanconnect and I get this error:

> "fail to connect: Operation now in progress"

Could you please help on that?

Comment: Are you using the `clickhouse-r` R package?

Comment: port=9000L,   (8123 - http , 9000 - tcp)  clickhouse::clickhouse uses tcp

Comment: Yes, I am using clickhouse-r. however, RClickhouse also returns same err

Comment: Hi @BahmanAjdari did you solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same error.

Comment: And I am also this error!